# split text and write to new file

Tags: python, string, text-files

I am trying to split data in inputfile.txt and write to Outputfile.txt

- Consider only first word & remove first letter
- Within the LIST the first line is root(Ex:a0) and remaining are
  connections(Ex:a3)
- If the root already exists(Ex:a0) then append the connections(Ex:a3,
  a9) to existing root(a0)
- In outputfile.txt after ":" all values are separated by tab

inputfile.txt

```
LIST : 2
a0 n
a3
LIST : 2
a0
a9 k
LIST : 2
a3
a5
a6 l
a8
LIST : 2
a4
a5
a6
a8
Outputfile.txt    
LIST 0 :  3       9
LIST 3 :  5       6     8
LIST 4 :  5       6     8
```

I am pretty new to python, I tried but no success

```
def main():
 updatedData = ""
 with open('inputfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        #print(line)
        test = line.split(" ",1)[0][1:]+ '\t'
        updatedData += test.replace('\n',' ')
```

Comment: Is this homework?  You'll need a flag to tell you whether this is the first line after a "LIST" or not.  If it's the first line after LIST, you remember the number and create a dictionary with an empty set().  If it's not the first line, you add the number to the set() for your remembered number.  You don't need `split`; you aren't going to do anything with the incoming "LIST" lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
master = None
tracking = {}
for line in open('inputfile.txt'):
    if line.startswith("LIST"):
        master = None
    elif master:
        tracking[master].add(line[1])
    else:
        master = line[1]
        if master not in tracking:
            tracking[master] = set()

for key,val in tracking.items():
    print( "LIST %s :" % key, '\t'.join(val) )
```

```
[timr@TimsPro:~/src]$ python x.py
LIST 0 : 9  3
LIST 3 : 8  5   6
LIST 4 : 8  5   6
```

Easy enough to sort before printing, if you need that.

**Edit to handle multi-digit keys.**

```
master = None
tracking = {}
for line in open('inputfile.txt'):
    word = line.split()[0]
    if word == "LIST":
        master = None
    elif master:
        tracking[master].add(word[1:])
    else:
        master = word[1:]
        if master not in tracking:
            tracking[master] = set()

for key,val in tracking.items():
    print( "LIST %s :" % key, '\t'.join(val) )
```

**Edit to not combine duplicate keys:**

If we don't need to combine the keys, the code is simpler.  We don't have to do any global tracking at all.  Every LIST block stands alone.  You just gather the nodes until you get to the end of the block.

```
key = None
for line in open('inputfile.txt'):
    word = line.split()[0]
    if word == "LIST":
        if key:
            print( "LIST %s :" % key, '\t'.join(gather) )
        key = None
    elif key:
        gather.append(word[1:])
    else:
        key = word[1:]
        gather = []

print( "LIST %s :" % key, '\t'.join(gather) )
```

Comment: In this code, if we give two or three digit number it will just take the first digit/letter instead of first word

Comment: Well, that wasn't in your example.  Easy to fix.  I'll edit the answer to handle that.

Comment: My bad, Thank you!  So can we achieve below output  LIST 0 : 3 LIST 0 : 9 LIST 3 : 5 6 8 LIST 4 : 5 6 8 with dictionaries. I believe LIST 0: 3 will be replaced with LIST 0: 9 because of same same key i.e 0

Comment: That is NOT the output you asked for in your question.  You SPECIFICALLY said you wanted to combine the keys, as in "LIST 0 : 3  9".  That's what my code does.  Have you even tried to run it?  If you don't care about combining them, then you don't need dictionaries at all.  Each LIST block will produce one line, and then you start over.

Comment: Your code is working fine. Not to combine LIST 0 : 3 / LIST 0 : 9 is a follow-up question.

Answer (score 1):

The requirements are a little vague (should roots be ordered?) but nonetheless here is a working example (at least for the input file and output in the op.) I included comments to explain how the algorithm works.

```
roots_dict = {} # Data structure to hold the roots and connections
reading_root = False # A simple state machine to know whether we are reading a root
prev_root = None

# A little function to fill the requirement "Consider only first word & remove first letter"
def get_line_item(line):
    # This check is for when you reach the end of the file and there is no new line
    if len(line) == 0:
        return False

    newline_removed = line[:(-1 if line[-1] == '\n' else len(line))] # Remove the final character if it is a newline, otherwise slice  the whole line
    line_words = newline_removed.split(' ') # Split the characters on the line into a list of space separated words
    return line_words[0][1:] # Return the first word, and only the characters starting from the second (ie, the 1th element)

with open('inputfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    line = True
    while line:
        line = f.readline()
        if line[:4] == 'LIST':
            reading_root = True
            continue
        if reading_root:
            root = get_line_item(line)
            if root not in roots_dict:
                roots_dict[root] = []
            prev_root = root
            reading_root = False
            continue
        connection = get_line_item(line)
        if connection:
            roots_dict[prev_root].append(connection)

# Printing in the format as described by the op. This could easily be written to an output file
for k in roots_dict:
    print(f'LIST {k} :\t', end='')
    for i in roots_dict[k]:
        print(f'{i}\t', end='')
    print()
```

Comment: Sorry for drafting the question vaguely, I am just understanding the code by editing it i.e I tried to remove the condition : "If the root already exists(Ex:a0) then append the connections(Ex:a3, a9) to existing root(a0)" but I am not getting desired out put

Comment: I understand that dictionaries map a key to a value. Duplicate keys are not allowed, and new entries replace old ones with the same key but I am trying to add a duplicate key as mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: What do you expect the output to be if you remove the condition ""If the root already exists(Ex:a0) then append the connections(Ex:a3, a9) to existing root(a0)"? And when you say you are trying to understand the code. Do you mean my code or the code you wrote?

Comment: LIST 0 :  3
LIST 0 :  9
LIST 3 :  5       6     8
LIST 4 :  5       6     8

Comment: So, do you want  `LIST 0 : 3` / `LIST 0:  9`, or do you want `LIST 0 : 3  9` as your question specifically says?

Comment: LIST 0 : 3 / LIST 0:  9